# XPath matcher does not work for meta tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, rspec

Have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="my id" property="fb:app_id" />
    <meta content="app name" property="og:site_name" />
    <meta content="social post" property="og:type" />
    <meta content="bsa" property="og:title" />
    <meta content="bsa" property="og:description" />
    <meta content="http://will-ferrell.lvh.me:3000/" property="og:url" />
  </head>
</html>
```

Trying to do this:

```
expect(page).to have_selector :xpath, '//head/meta[@property="fb:app_id"]'
expect(page).to have_selector :xpath, '//head/meta[@property="og:site_name"]'
expect(page).to have_selector :xpath, '//head/meta[@property="og:type"]'
expect(page).to have_selector :xpath, '//head/meta[@property="og:title"]'
expect(page).to have_selector :xpath, '//head/meta[@property="og:description"]'
expect(page).to have_selector :xpath, '//head/meta[@property="og:url"]'
```

And it does not work. Says it can't find the selector.
Any idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand which library you are using to parse HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For invisible elements need use [option](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders%3aall) - **visible: false**

Example:

```
expect(page).to have_selector :xpath, '//head/meta[@property="og:url"]', visible: false
```